# D3.js column chart inversing when adding text

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a basic column chart using divs from the example in allignedleft and the one mike has posted. The chart works except when i add text, it inverses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div.abc {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 75px;
 background-color: teal;
 margin-right: 2px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.8.1"></script>
<script>

var dataset = [16,13,8,2,1,10,0,5,24,15,2,6,12];


d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("div")
.attr("class", "abc")
.style("height", function(d) {
    var barHeight = d * 5;
    return barHeight + "px";
})
.style("margin-top",function(d) {
    var barHeight = d * 5;
    return 500 - barHeight;
})
.style("text-align","center")
.style("color","black")
.text(function (d) { return d; });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Sriram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the vertical alignment of the text in the divs. If you add

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

to your CSS, it should work again. Note that some of your divs are too small for the text. In these cases, the labels won't be aligned with the rest. I recommend that you create separate divs for the labels and place them accordingly.